# How to get the values from a Wagtail CMS Stream field panel using Django Models?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, wagtail-streamfield

I'm building a webpage using wagtail CMS, Django, Postgresql and at the bottom of the page, I'm building a section where I would display the videos using pagination.

I'm trying to retrieve the data from Django Models using `all_posts = MultiBlogPage.objects.values("all_blogs_content_pages")`

and I'm getting the output as

```
<PageQuerySet [{'all_blogs_content_pages': 
[
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ee2d21d0>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ed8fa2e8>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35f617e6a0>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ed90aac8>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ed90af60>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ed90a978>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ed90ae48>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ee2b9320>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ee2b9630>,
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ee339f28>, 
<wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block.StreamValue.StreamChild object at 0x7f35ee339470>
]}]>
```

Could someone please look at my code below and let me know how to get the exact values from Django Models ?

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MultiBlogPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context['multiblog_page'] = self
    
    // The name of the stream field panel is "all_blogs_content_pages"
    all_posts = MultiBlogPage.objects.values("all_blogs_content_pages")

    print("all_posts...",all_posts)

    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 3)
    print("paginator", paginator)
    page = request.GET.get("page")

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)        
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    
    context["posts"] = posts
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Wagtail models can be used like standard django models, so converting the models to a list of dicts does not seem necessary.

`live()`, filters only published versions, and `specific()` gets the actual model from your models.py rather than the base Page class.

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MultiBlogPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    context['multiblog_page'] = self
    
    // The name of the stream field panel is "all_blogs_content_pages"
    all_posts = MultiBlogPage.objects.live().specific()

    print("all_posts...",all_posts)

    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 3)
    print("paginator", paginator)
    page = request.GET.get("page")

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)        
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    
    context["posts"] = posts
    return context
```

template.html

```
<li>
  {{ post.all_blogs_content_pages }}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful